# build setup with database

Tags: c#

I have written the code and finished the project. It is a window app in c#. I also have a database in sql server 2005 which I used it in the application. I need to create a setup for it so that any user can install it in his machine. build->publish and then following the wizard is the right way perhaps.. but what about the database?

The same database I made won't be in all computers, so I need that database also bind with my application.

Comment: What do you mean by setup?  Do you mean the setup for building the code, or the setup for installing?  What do you mean by attaching the database to the setup?

Comment: i have build the code and finished the project.its a window app in c#.
i also have a database in sql server 2005 which i use it in the application.

i need to create a setup for it so that the user can install it.
build->publish and then following the wizard is the right way..but what about the database??the same database wont be in all computers.
so i need that database also bind with my application.i hope i have made myself clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to some intro level tutorials, this should get you started.  I would focus on creating some sample "Hello World" type applications before you dive into database programming.  If you don't start small with this stuff, it can get frustrating.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are looking for basic information on setting up a project, to truly document this is going to take a lot more than a post.

The basic project setup, is done via Visual Studio and the "File" -> "New" -> "New Project" option.  You can then select the type of project you need and that will then setup the project for you.

For the database conection, you will want to look into the items in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.

Comment: i have build the code and finished the project.its a window app in c#. i also have a database in sql server 2005 which i used it in the application. i need to create a setup for it so that the user can install it. build->publish and then following the wizard is the right way..but what about the database??the same database wont be in all computers. so i need that database also bind with my application.i hope i have made myself clear. 
now whats the procedure to creat that setup?